# Can HAProxy loadbalance multiple requests send through single TCP connection

Tags: tcp, haproxy

Our client to HAProxy establishes single TCP connection and continues to send messages. We would like to know, is there are way to load balance those messages across the services sitting behind HAProxy. Please advise.

Comment: Yes it can. Check the configuration in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865109/loadbalancing-logback-logstash-logs-using-haproxy/36883667#36883667) or my answer below

Comment: After prototyping the answer posted below, I think the answer is no HAProxy cannot do this.

Comment: It is possible to load balance multiple HTTP/1.1 requests on the same TCP connection across multiple backed servers. This is the default HA proxy behavior with http mode. Note that we are talking about HTTP keep alive and not HTTP pipelining.  Pipelining might not be supported by LB's on the backend.