# Loadbalancing Logback logstash logs using HAProxy

Tags: tcp, logstash, haproxy

IP Address:

1. Web Application  -> `192.168.x.209`
2. HAProxy -> `192.168.x.211`
3. Logstash Shipper -> `192.168.x.210`

With the below configuration, HAProxy is not able to receive logs from Logstash application and thus logstash shipper is not able to receive the logs.

Following are the configurations I did:

**WebApplication - logback.xml**

```
<appender name="stash"
    class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashAccessTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>192.168.x.211:5001</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
</appender>
```

**HAProxy Config**

```
listen logstash
    bind  :5001
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    option tcplog
    server logstash01 192.168.x.212:5001 check
    server logstash02 192.168.x.210:5001 check
```

**Logstash Shipper - config**

```
input{
    tcp{
            type => "log1"
            port => 5001
            codec => "json"
    }
    tcp{
            type => "log2"
            port => 5002
            codec => "json"
    }
output {
            stdout{
            codec => rubydebug
    }}
```

Is there anything wrong with the configuration? help required.

Comment: Any app logs, tcpdumps? Can you see packets from app on haproxy host? Can haproxy connect to backend (eg haproxy stats)? Can you see packets from haproxy host, except healtchecks?

Comment: tcpdump->  IP 192.168.x.211.commplex-link > 192.168.100.209.46451: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3725007976, win 0, length 0
17:02:51.504420 IP 192.168.100.209.33372 > 192.168.100.211.rfe: Flags [S], seq 3529915276, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 108239448 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 192.168.x.211 > 192.168.100.209: ICMP host 192.168.100.211 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68
IP 192.168.x.209.46466 > 192.168.100.211.commplex-link: Flags [S], seq 2224514751, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 108240051 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

This was because firewall rules were active. After shutting it down, things worked as expected.

```
service iptables stop 
setenv 0
```